# Can not figure out how to get the generated email from my function

Tags: python, function, return

I am unable to understand/get email to return

```
import time
import names
import random
import os

email_domains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com', 'hotmail.com', 'outlook.com']


def generate_account_details():
    first_name = names.get_first_name()
    last_name = names.get_last_name()
    password_name = names.get_first_name()
    email = first_name.lower() + last_name.lower() + str(randint(1, 100000)) + "@" + random.choice(email_domains)
    password = password_name.lower() + str(randint(1, 1000))

generate_account_details(email)
```

NameError: name 'email' is not defined

Comment: The error explains your exact issue, and likely the line it occurs on. `email` is not a defined variable, your function also does not accept any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, your issue is caused by the fact that you put `email` as a parameter when calling your function `generate_account_details()`.  For it to work, you'll need to do 1 of 2 things:

1. Remove the `email` from the function call
2. Add the parameter in the function definition

Personally, I'd go for #1 because then you minimize the need to re-write your function